# .NET MAUI - Picker TextColor Bug

Tags: maui

I'm not able to set the `TextColor` of a Picker to "White".

It turns to white once I select an element but it turns to black as soon as I hover over the control.

```xml
<Picker TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Green" Title="Select a monkey">
    <Picker.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
            <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
            <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </Picker.ItemsSource>
</Picker>
```

Before Hover:

[image: Before Hover]

After Hover:

[image: After Hover]

Comment: I have done a sample and met the same problem. And then I found it's an exited issue on the github, you can check [the link](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7924).

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code to your Platforms/Windows/App.xaml file

```
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxForegroundPointerOver"
                  Color="White" />
```